# Display multiline textbox bound to an array of strings with each element string on a separate line, allowing editing

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an array of strings where StringArray[0] = "FOR DEPOSIT ONLY", StringArray[1] = "ANY BANK OF ANYTOWN", StringArray[2] = "ACCOUNT #123456789"; there are more array elements, but assume these are the only ones populated.

I need to display these strings in a multiline textbox like this:

FOR DEPOSIT ONLY
ANY BANK OF ANYTOWN
ACCOUNT #123456789

A user should be able to edit the textbox like this:

FOR DEPOSIT ONLY
MY BANK OF MY TOWN
ACCOUNT #987654321

and have the array be saved as follows:  StringArray[0] = "FOR DEPOSIT ONLY", StringArray[1] = "My BANK OF MY TOWN", StringArray[2] = "ACCOUNT #987654321"

After looking at this site, I found something like this:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}">
            <Binding Path="StringArray[0]"/>
            <Binding Path="StringArray[1]"/>
            <Binding Path="StringArray[2]"/>
            <Binding Source="{x:Static System:Enviroment.NewLine}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

The "System" variable is properly defined at the top of my XAML file.

This code gave me the error "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath".  The error appears to be on the "Binding Source" line.  What do I need to add to this to make my textbox work;if a path is required on the "Binding Source" line, what would it be?  Thanks.

Comment: Set `Mode="OneWay"` on the last binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Mode=OneWay` to the newline binding should get rid of your warning. That said, your bindings don't put each array element on its own line, but concatenates them. This approach displays what you want:

```
<TextBox
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    AcceptsReturn="True">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}">
            <Binding Path="StringArray[0]" ElementName="self" />
            <Binding Source="{x:Static system:Environment.NewLine}" Mode="OneWay" />
            <Binding Path="StringArray[1]" ElementName="self" />
            <Binding Source="{x:Static system:Environment.NewLine}" Mode="OneWay" />
            <Binding Path="StringArray[2]" ElementName="self" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

As for getting the string array updated, I'm not sure you can do that without a converter. You can throw out the `StringFormat` and do the following instead:

```
<TextBox
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    AcceptsReturn="True">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="StringArray[0]" ElementName="self" />
            <Binding Path="StringArray[1]" ElementName="self" />
            <Binding Path="StringArray[2]" ElementName="self" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Here I set `x:Name="self"` on my Window class, which declares the `StringArray`.

With the converter defined like this:

```
public sealed class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string stringValue = (string)value;
        return stringValue.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

Reference the converter somewhere in your XAML, e.g.:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <multiLine:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

But: Since there's semantics associated with each line (account type, location, account #) I think you'd be better off using individual text boxes and straight data binding for each element of your data structure.